# « An Error occurred during authorization » using Linkedin API

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use the Linkedin API in order to publish some content on my company page but I'm facing a very weird error. Here is what I did up to now.

First of all, I **registered an application** with the following parameters :

- OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs / OAuth 1.0a Accept/Cancel Redirect URL : https://mywebsite.com/linkedin/demo.php
- Default Scope : all checked parameters

Then I put in my linkedin folder the following files :

**auth.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();

$config['base_url']             =   'http://mywebsite.com/linkedin/auth.php';
$config['callback_url']         =   'http://mywebsite.com/linkedin/demo.php';
$config['linkedin_access']      =   '************';
$config['linkedin_secret']      =   '************';

include_once "linkedin.php";

$linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );

$linkedin->getRequestToken();
$_SESSION['requestToken'] = serialize($linkedin->request_token);

header("Location: " . $linkedin->generateAuthorizeUrl());;
?>
```

**demo.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();

$config['base_url']             =   'http://mywebsite.com/linkedin/auth.php';
$config['callback_url']         =   'http://mywebsite.com/linkedin/demo.php';
$config['linkedin_access']      =   '************';
$config['linkedin_secret']      =   '************';

include_once "linkedin.php";

$linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );
if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])){
    $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']     = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

    $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
    $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
    $linkedin->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

    $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = serialize($linkedin->access_token);
    header("Location: " . $config['callback_url']);
    exit;
} else{
    $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
    $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
    $linkedin->access_token     =   unserialize($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
}

$xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url)");

echo '<pre>';
echo 'My Profile Info';
echo $xml_response;
echo '<br />';
echo '</pre>';

$search_response = $linkedin->search("?company-name=facebook&count=10");

echo $search_response;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($search_response);

echo '<pre>';
echo 'Look people who worked in facebook';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I also put the **linkedin.php** and the **OAuth.php** files that I easily found online :

**Linkedin.php**

```
<?php
require_once("OAuth.php");

class LinkedIn {
public $base_url = "http://api.linkedin.com";
public $secure_base_url = "https://api.linkedin.com";
public $oauth_callback = "oob";
public $consumer;
public $request_token;
public $access_token;
public $oauth_verifier;
public $signature_method;
public $request_token_path;
public $access_token_path;
public $authorize_path;
public $debug = false;

function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_callback = NULL) {
if($oauth_callback) {
  $this->oauth_callback = $oauth_callback;
}

$this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $this->oauth_callback);
$this->signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$this->request_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/requestToken";
$this->access_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/accessToken";
$this->authorize_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/authorize";
}

function getRequestToken() {
$consumer = $this->consumer;
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL, "GET", $this->request_token_path);
$request->set_parameter("oauth_callback", $this->oauth_callback);
$request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $consumer, NULL);
$headers = Array();
$url = $request->to_url();
$response = $this->httpRequest($url, $headers, "GET");
parse_str($response, $response_params);
$this->request_token = new OAuthConsumer($response_params['oauth_token'], $response_params['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
}

function generateAuthorizeUrl() {
$consumer = $this->consumer;
$request_token = $this->request_token;
return $this->authorize_path . "?oauth_token=" . $request_token->key;
}

function getAccessToken($oauth_verifier) {
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->request_token, "GET", $this->access_token_path);
$request->set_parameter("oauth_verifier", $oauth_verifier);
$request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->request_token);
$headers = Array();
$url = $request->to_url();
$response = $this->httpRequest($url, $headers, "GET");
parse_str($response, $response_params);
if($debug) {
  echo $response . "\n";
}
$this->access_token = new OAuthConsumer($response_params['oauth_token'], $response_params['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
}

function getProfile($resource = "~") {
$profile_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/" . $resource;
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $profile_url);
$request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
$auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");
if ($debug) {
  echo $auth_header;
}
// $response will now hold the XML document
$response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "GET");
return $response;
}

function setStatus($status) {
$status_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/~/current-status";
echo "Setting status...\n";
$xml = "<current-status>" . htmlspecialchars($status, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8") . "</current-status>";
echo $xml . "\n";
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "PUT", $status_url);
$request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
$auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");
if ($debug) {
  echo $auth_header . "\n";
}
$response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "GET");
return $response;
}

function search($parameters) {
$search_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/" . $parameters;
echo "Performing search for: " . $parameters . "\n";
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $search_url);
$request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
$auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");
if ($debug) {
  echo $request->get_signature_base_string() . "\n";
  echo $auth_header . "\n";
}
$response = $this->httpRequest($search_url, $auth_header, "GET");
return $response;
}

function httpRequest($url, $auth_header, $method, $body = NULL) {
if (!$method) {
  $method = "GET";
};
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header)); // Set the headers.
if ($body) {
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header, "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"));
}
$data = curl_exec($curl);
if ($this->debug) {
  echo $data . "\n";
}
curl_close($curl);
return $data;
}
}
```

**OAuth.php**

```
    <?php

class OAuthConsumer {
  public $key;
  public $secret;

  function __construct($key, $secret, $callback_url=NULL) {
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->secret = $secret;
    $this->callback_url = $callback_url;
  }

  function __toString() {
    return "OAuthConsumer[key=$this->key,secret=$this->secret]";
  }
}

class OAuthToken {
  public $key;
  public $secret;

  function __construct($key, $secret) {
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->secret = $secret;
  }

  function to_string() {
    return "oauth_token=" .
           OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986($this->key) .
           "&oauth_token_secret=" .
           OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986($this->secret);
  }

  function __toString() {
    return $this->to_string();
  }
}

abstract class OAuthSignatureMethod {
  abstract public function get_name();
  abstract public function build_signature($request, $consumer, $token);
  public function check_signature($request, $consumer, $token, $signature) {
    $built = $this->build_signature($request, $consumer, $token);
    return $built == $signature;
  }
}

class OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 extends OAuthSignatureMethod {
  function get_name() {
    return "HMAC-SHA1";
  }
  public function build_signature($request, $consumer, $token) {
    $base_string = $request->get_signature_base_string();
    $request->base_string = $base_string;
    $key_parts = array(
      $consumer->secret,
      ($token) ? $token->secret : ""
    );
    $key_parts = OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986($key_parts);
    $key = implode('&', $key_parts);
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $key, true));
  }
}

class OAuthSignatureMethod_PLAINTEXT extends OAuthSignatureMethod {
  public function get_name() {
    return "PLAINTEXT";
  }
  public function build_signature($request, $consumer, $token) {
    $key_parts = array($consumer->secret,($token) ? $token->secret : "");
    $key_parts = OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986($key_parts);
    $key = implode('&', $key_parts);
    $request->base_string = $key;
    return $key;
  }
}

abstract class OAuthSignatureMethod_RSA_SHA1 extends OAuthSignatureMethod {
  public function get_name() { return "RSA-SHA1";}
  protected abstract function fetch_public_cert(&$request);
  public function build_signature($request, $consumer, $token) {
    $base_string = $request->get_signature_base_string();
    $request->base_string = $base_string;
    $cert = $this->fetch_private_cert($request);
    $privatekeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($cert);
    $ok = openssl_sign($base_string, $signature, $privatekeyid);
    openssl_free_key($privatekeyid);
    return base64_encode($signature);
  }
  public function check_signature($request, $consumer, $token, $signature) {
    $decoded_sig = base64_decode($signature);
    $base_string = $request->get_signature_base_string();
    $cert = $this->fetch_public_cert($request);
    $publickeyid = openssl_get_publickey($cert);
    $ok = openssl_verify($base_string, $decoded_sig, $publickeyid);
    openssl_free_key($publickeyid);
    return $ok == 1;
  }
}

class OAuthRequest {
  private $parameters;
  private $http_method;
  private $http_url;
  // for debug purposes
  public $base_string;
  public static $version = '1.0';
  public static $POST_INPUT = 'php://input';
  function __construct($http_method, $http_url, $parameters=NULL) {
    @$parameters or $parameters = array();
    $parameters = array_merge( OAuthUtil::parse_parameters(parse_url($http_url, PHP_URL_QUERY)), $parameters);
    $this->parameters = $parameters;
    $this->http_method = $http_method;
    $this->http_url = $http_url;
  }

  public static function from_request($http_method=NULL, $http_url=NULL, $parameters=NULL) {
    $scheme = (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on")
              ? 'http'
              : 'https';
    @$http_url or $http_url = $scheme .
                              '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .
                              ':' .
                              $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] .
                              $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    @$http_method or $http_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];


    if (!$parameters) {
      $request_headers = OAuthUtil::get_headers();
      $parameters = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
      if ($http_method == "POST"
          && @strstr($request_headers["Content-Type"],
                     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
          ) {
        $post_data = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters(
          file_get_contents(self::$POST_INPUT)
        );
        $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $post_data);
      }
      if (@substr($request_headers['Authorization'], 0, 6) == "OAuth ") {
        $header_parameters = OAuthUtil::split_header(
          $request_headers['Authorization']
        );
        $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $header_parameters);
      }
    }
    return new OAuthRequest($http_method, $http_url, $parameters);
  }

  public static function from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, $http_method, $http_url, $parameters=NULL) {
    @$parameters or $parameters = array();
    $defaults = array("oauth_version" => OAuthRequest::$version,
                      //"oauth_nonce" => OAuthRequest::generate_nonce(),
                      "oauth_timestamp" => OAuthRequest::generate_timestamp(),
                      "oauth_consumer_key" => $consumer->key);
    if ($token)
      $defaults['oauth_token'] = $token->key;

    $parameters = array_merge($defaults, $parameters);

    return new OAuthRequest($http_method, $http_url, $parameters);
  }

  public function set_parameter($name, $value, $allow_duplicates = true) {
    if ($allow_duplicates && isset($this->parameters[$name])) {
      if (is_scalar($this->parameters[$name])) {
        $this->parameters[$name] = array($this->parameters[$name]);
      }

      $this->parameters[$name][] = $value;
    } else {
      $this->parameters[$name] = $value;
    }
  }

  public function get_parameter($name) {
    return isset($this->parameters[$name]) ? $this->parameters[$name] : null;
  }

  public function get_parameters() {
    return $this->parameters;
  }

  public function unset_parameter($name) {
    unset($this->parameters[$name]);
  }

  public function get_signable_parameters() {
    $params = $this->parameters;
    if (isset($params['oauth_signature'])) {
      unset($params['oauth_signature']);
    }
    return OAuthUtil::build_http_query($params);
  }

  public function get_signature_base_string() {
    $parts = array(
      $this->get_normalized_http_method(),
      $this->get_normalized_http_url(),
      $this->get_signable_parameters()
    );
    $parts = OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986($parts);

    return implode('&', $parts);
  }

  public function get_normalized_http_method() {
    return strtoupper($this->http_method);
  }

  public function get_normalized_http_url() {
    $parts = parse_url($this->http_url);
    $port = @$parts['port'];
    $scheme = $parts['scheme'];
    $host = $parts['host'];
    $path = @$parts['path'];
    $port or $port = ($scheme == 'https') ? '443' : '80';
    if (($scheme == 'https' && $port != '443')
        || ($scheme == 'http' && $port != '80')) {
      $host = "$host:$port";
    }
    return "$scheme://$host$path";
  }

  public function to_url() {
    $post_data = $this->to_postdata();
    $out = $this->get_normalized_http_url();
    if ($post_data) {
      $out .= '?'.$post_data;
    }
    return $out;
  }

  public function to_postdata() {
    return OAuthUtil::build_http_query($this->parameters);
  }

  public function to_header($realm=null) {
    if($realm)
      $out = 'Authorization: OAuth realm="' . OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986($realm) . '"';
    else
      $out = 'Authorization: OAuth';

    $total = array();
    foreach ($this->parameters as $k => $v) {
      if (substr($k, 0, 5) != "oauth") continue;
      if (is_array($v)) {
        throw new OAuthException('Arrays not supported in headers');
      }
      $out .= ',' .
              OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986($k) .
              '="' .
              OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986($v) .
              '"';
    }
    return $out;
  }

  public function __toString() {
    return $this->to_url();
  }

  public function sign_request($signature_method, $consumer, $token) {
    $this->set_parameter(
      "oauth_signature_method",
      $signature_method->get_name(),
      false
    );
    $signature = $this->build_signature($signature_method, $consumer, $token);
    $this->set_parameter("oauth_signature", $signature, false);
  }

  public function build_signature($signature_method, $consumer, $token) {
    $signature = $signature_method->build_signature($this, $consumer, $token);
    return $signature;
  }

  private static function generate_timestamp() {
    return time();
  }

  private static function generate_nonce() {
    $mt = microtime();
    $rand = mt_rand();

    return md5($mt . $rand); // md5s look nicer than numbers
  }
}

class OAuthServer {
  protected $timestamp_threshold = 300; // in seconds, five minutes
  protected $version = '1.0';             // hi blaine
  protected $signature_methods = array();
  protected $data_store;

  function __construct($data_store) {
    $this->data_store = $data_store;
  }

  public function add_signature_method($signature_method) {
    $this->signature_methods[$signature_method->get_name()] =
      $signature_method;
  }

  public function fetch_request_token(&$request) {
    $this->get_version($request);
    $consumer = $this->get_consumer($request);
    $token = NULL;
    $this->check_signature($request, $consumer, $token);
    $callback = $request->get_parameter('oauth_callback');
    $new_token = $this->data_store->new_request_token($consumer, $callback);
    return $new_token;
  }

  public function fetch_access_token(&$request) {
    $this->get_version($request);

    $consumer = $this->get_consumer($request);

    // requires authorized request token
    $token = $this->get_token($request, $consumer, "request");

    $this->check_signature($request, $consumer, $token);

    // Rev A change
    $verifier = $request->get_parameter('oauth_verifier');
    $new_token = $this->data_store->new_access_token($token, $consumer, $verifier);

    return $new_token;
  }


  public function verify_request(&$request) {
    $this->get_version($request);
    $consumer = $this->get_consumer($request);
    $token = $this->get_token($request, $consumer, "access");
    $this->check_signature($request, $consumer, $token);
    return array($consumer, $token);
  }


  private function get_version(&$request) {
    $version = $request->get_parameter("oauth_version");
    if (!$version) {
      // Service Providers MUST assume the protocol version to be 1.0 if this parameter is not present.
      // Chapter 7.0 ("Accessing Protected Ressources")
      $version = '1.0';
    }
    if ($version !== $this->version) {
      throw new OAuthException("OAuth version '$version' not supported");
    }
    return $version;
  }


  private function get_signature_method(&$request) {
    $signature_method =
        @$request->get_parameter("oauth_signature_method");

    if (!$signature_method) {
      // According to chapter 7 ("Accessing Protected Ressources") the signature-method
      // parameter is required, and we can't just fallback to PLAINTEXT
      throw new OAuthException('No signature method parameter. This parameter is required');
    }

    if (!in_array($signature_method,
                  array_keys($this->signature_methods))) {
      throw new OAuthException(
        "Signature method '$signature_method' not supported " .
        "try one of the following: " .
        implode(", ", array_keys($this->signature_methods))
      );
    }
    return $this->signature_methods[$signature_method];
  }

  private function get_consumer(&$request) {
    $consumer_key = @$request->get_parameter("oauth_consumer_key");
    if (!$consumer_key) {
      throw new OAuthException("Invalid consumer key");
    }

    $consumer = $this->data_store->lookup_consumer($consumer_key);
    if (!$consumer) {
      throw new OAuthException("Invalid consumer");
    }

    return $consumer;
  }

  private function get_token(&$request, $consumer, $token_type="access") {
    $token_field = @$request->get_parameter('oauth_token');
    $token = $this->data_store->lookup_token(
      $consumer, $token_type, $token_field
    );
    if (!$token) {
      throw new OAuthException("Invalid $token_type token: $token_field");
    }
    return $token;
  }

  private function check_signature(&$request, $consumer, $token) {
    $timestamp = @$request->get_parameter('oauth_timestamp');
    $nonce = @$request->get_parameter('oauth_nonce');

    $this->check_timestamp($timestamp);
    $this->check_nonce($consumer, $token, $nonce, $timestamp);

    $signature_method = $this->get_signature_method($request);

    $signature = $request->get_parameter('oauth_signature');
    $valid_sig = $signature_method->check_signature(
      $request,
      $consumer,
      $token,
      $signature
    );

    if (!$valid_sig) {
      throw new OAuthException("Invalid signature");
    }
  }


  private function check_timestamp($timestamp) {
    if( ! $timestamp )
      throw new OAuthException(
        'Missing timestamp parameter. The parameter is required'
      );

    // verify that timestamp is recentish
    $now = time();
    if (abs($now - $timestamp) > $this->timestamp_threshold) {
      throw new OAuthException(
        "Expired timestamp, yours $timestamp, ours $now"
      );
    }
  }


  private function check_nonce($consumer, $token, $nonce, $timestamp) {
    if( ! $nonce )
      throw new OAuthException(
        'Missing nonce parameter. The parameter is required'
      );

    // verify that the nonce is uniqueish
    $found = $this->data_store->lookup_nonce(
      $consumer,
      $token,
      $nonce,
      $timestamp
    );
    if ($found) {
      throw new OAuthException("Nonce already used: $nonce");
    }
  }
}

class OAuthDataStore {
  function lookup_consumer($consumer_key) {
    // implement me
  }

  function lookup_token($consumer, $token_type, $token) {
    // implement me
  }

  function lookup_nonce($consumer, $token, $nonce, $timestamp) {
    // implement me
  }

  function new_request_token($consumer, $callback = null) {
    // return a new token attached to this consumer
  }

  function new_access_token($token, $consumer, $verifier = null) {

  }
}

class OAuthUtil {
  public static function urlencode_rfc3986($input) {
    if (is_array($input)) {
      return array_map(array('OAuthUtil', 'urlencode_rfc3986'), $input);
    } else if (is_scalar($input)) {
      return str_replace(
        '+',
        ' ',
        str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($input))
      );
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  public static function urldecode_rfc3986($string) {
    return urldecode($string);
  }

  public static function split_header($header, $only_allow_oauth_parameters = true) {
    $pattern = '/(([-_a-z]*)=("([^"]*)"|([^,]*)),?)/';
    $offset = 0;
    $params = array();
    while (preg_match($pattern, $header, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset) > 0) {
      $match = $matches[0];
      $header_name = $matches[2][0];
      $header_content = (isset($matches[5])) ? $matches[5][0] : $matches[4][0];
      if (preg_match('/^oauth_/', $header_name) || !$only_allow_oauth_parameters) {
        $params[$header_name] = OAuthUtil::urldecode_rfc3986($header_content);
      }
      $offset = $match[1] + strlen($match[0]);
    }

    if (isset($params['realm'])) {
      unset($params['realm']);
    }
    return $params;
  }

  public static function get_headers() {
    if (function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
      $headers = apache_request_headers();

      $out = array();
      foreach( $headers AS $key => $value ) {
        $key = str_replace(
            " ",
            "-",
            ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("-", " ", $key)))
          );
        $out[$key] = $value;
      }
    } else {
      $out = array();
      foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 5) == "HTTP_") {
          $key = str_replace(
            " ",
            "-",
            ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("_", " ", substr($key, 5))))
          );
          $out[$key] = $value;
        }
      }
    }
    return $out;
  }

  public static function parse_parameters( $input ) {
    if (!isset($input) || !$input) return array();

    $pairs = explode('&', $input);

    $parsed_parameters = array();
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
      $split = explode('=', $pair, 2);
      $parameter = OAuthUtil::urldecode_rfc3986($split[0]);
      $value = isset($split[1]) ? OAuthUtil::urldecode_rfc3986($split[1]) : '';

      if (isset($parsed_parameters[$parameter])) {
        // We have already recieved parameter(s) with this name, so add to the list
        // of parameters with this name

        if (is_scalar($parsed_parameters[$parameter])) {
          // This is the first duplicate, so transform scalar (string) into an array
          // so we can add the duplicates
          $parsed_parameters[$parameter] = array($parsed_parameters[$parameter]);
        }

        $parsed_parameters[$parameter][] = $value;
      } else {
        $parsed_parameters[$parameter] = $value;
      }
    }
    return $parsed_parameters;
  }

  public static function build_http_query($params) {
    if (!$params) return '';

    // Urlencode both keys and values
    $keys = OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986(array_keys($params));
    $values = OAuthUtil::urlencode_rfc3986(array_values($params));
    $params = array_combine($keys, $values);

    uksort($params, 'strcmp');

    $pairs = array();
    foreach ($params as $parameter => $value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
        natsort($value);
        foreach ($value as $duplicate_value) {
          $pairs[] = $parameter . '=' . $duplicate_value;
        }
      } else {
        $pairs[] = $parameter . '=' . $value;
      }
    }
    // For each parameter, the name is separated from the corresponding value by an '=' character (ASCII code 61)
    // Each name-value pair is separated by an '&' character (ASCII code 38)
    return implode('&', $pairs);
  }
}
?>
```

But when I tried to get the auth.php page, I get this error :

> An Error occurred during authorization, please try again later.

And I end up on this page : https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=

So, is it a problem on my side or on their side ?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the location of the sources for `linkedin.php` and `OAuth.php` because there are more scripts like that with the same name.

Comment: @HansZ. I edited my post with the linkedin.php and OAuth.php files I found online.

Comment: use `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` in the `httpRequest` function and verify that you actually get back a token in the getRequestToken request. There could be a mismatch in the settings for callback, key and/or secret.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you told me. I added `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` right after `$curl = curl_init();` in the `httpRequest` function but I continue to get the error…

Comment: yes, but now you should be able to look in to the logs on the server that runs the PHP code to find out more about what goes over the wire and inspect if any error messages are displayed there (PHP error reporting needs to be enabled with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: I checked the logs and I found severals errors : `Array to string conversion` in `linkedin.php` at the line `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header));` and `Undefined index: oauth_token / oauth_token_secret` in `linkedin.php` at the end of the `getRequestToken` function when we call `OAuthConsumer`.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Use this line in your `function httpRequest` in `linkedin.php`

Note:
Download https://github.com/Thamaraiselvam/Linkedin-Api
I have cleared all errors

Comment: I added the line right after `$curl = curl_init();` but when I try to access the auth.php page I continue to get the error. Is there anything else I need to do ?

Comment: did you try my answer? what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: https://github.com/Thamaraiselvam/Linkedin-Api check here i have updated and cleared all errors , download and use it

Comment: I updated my files with yours (of course, I added my API key and secret key) and now if I try to access the auth.php page, I’m getting a blank page ): Do I need to do something more ?

Comment: it works me dear , i think you do some mistakes ! download my zip folder and just change your keys only.

Comment: But it's exactly what I did :( On the linkedin website, where you registered your app, what did you enter in the OAuth User Agreement section at "OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs: " ? (I entered http://mydomain/linkedin/demo.php, is it ok ?)

Comment: add `https://` and dont want to add `demo.php` example `https://yourdomain/linkedin/`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the blank page… I really don't understand. I only modified `auth.php` and `demo.php` in order to set my keys.